# Image responsive design not working on mobile phones?

Tags: css

I hope it's ok to share URL: http://www.amigote.com/user/marcus_avrelius

The header image gets resized on PC browsers but for some reason doesn't work on cell phones, shows way too high! I am not sure why please help me to find it issue?

Update! It's not working on default browser? How can I take care of that? I installed firefox app and it works!

Comment: It's works, what is the problem? Do you want to show another small image on mobile browsers?

Comment: It's not working on cell phone bro. The image height doesn't get resized automatically to adjust to the screen resolution it maintains the height.

Answer (score 0):

Use 100% width so it will automatic re-sized according to browser width.
OR
You can use media query for same.